# Replacing everything but a specific pattern in a string (Oracle)

Tags: regex, oracle

I want to replace everything in a string with '' except for a given pattern using Oracle's `regexp_replace`.

In my case the pattern refers to German licence plates. The patterns is contained in the usage column (`verwendungszweck_bez`) of a revenue table (of a bank). The pattern can be matched by (`[a-z]{1,3})[- ]([a-z]{1,2}) ?([0-9]{1,4}`). Now I'd like to reverse the matching pattern in order to match everything except for the pattern.
The usage column looks like this:

```
ALLIANZ VERSICHERUNGS-AG VERTRAG AS-9028000568 KFZ-VERSICHERUNG KFZ-VERS. XX-Y 427 01.01.19 - 31.12.19
```

`XX-Y 427` would be the pattern I'm interested in. The string can contain more than one license plate:

```
AXA VERSICHERUNG AG 40301089910 KFZ HAFTPFLICHT ABC-RM10 37,35 + 40330601383 KFZ HAFTPFLIVHT ABC-LX 283 21,19
```

In this case I need `ABC-RM10` and `ABC-LX 283`.

So far I just replace everything from the string with `regexp_replace`:

```
regexp_replace(lower(a.verwendungszweck_bez),'^(.*?)kfz','')
```

because there's always '`kfz`' in the string and the licence plate information follows (not necessarily direct) after that.

```
upper(regexp_replace(regexp_substr(regexp_replace(lower(a.verwendungszweck_bez),'(^(.*?)kfz',''),'([a-z]{1,3})[- ]([a-z]{1,2}) ?([0-9]{1,4})',1,1),'([a-z]{1,3})[- ]([a-z]{1,2}) ?([0-9]{1,4})','\1-\2 \3'))
```

This works but I'm sure there's a better solution.

The result should be a list of customers, licence plates and count of cars like this:

```
Customer|licence plates         |count

1234567 |XX-Y 427| 1
1255599 |ABC-RM 10 + ABC-LX 283| 2
```

Comment: Why don't you just *take* what you need instead of erasing everything else?

Comment: Good idea. That's exactly what I'm doing now but I'd like to know how to to it in another way.

Comment: Also it's necessary to reduce the string in order to avoid wrong matches. In the sceond example otherwise a wrong licence plate UNG AG 4030 would have been found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive sub-query to find the items. Also, you can use `UPPER` and `TRANSLATE` to normalise the data to remove the optional separators in the number plates and convert it into a single case:

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT 'ALLIANZ VERSICHERUNGS-AG VERTRAG AS-9028000568 KFZ-VERSICHERUNG KFZ-VERS. XX-Y 427 01.01.19 - 31.12.19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
-- UNG AG 4030 should not match
SELECT 'AXA VERSICHERUNG AG 40301089910 KFZ HAFTPFLICHT ABC-RM10 37,35 + 40330601383 KFZ HAFTPFLIVHT ABC-LX 283 21,19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
-- Multiple matches adjacent to each other
SELECT 'AA-A1BB-BB222CC C3333' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
-- Duplicate values with different separators and cases
SELECT 'AA-A1 AA-A 1 aa a1' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
WITH items ( value, item, next_pos ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         TRANSLATE( UPPER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^a-z]|^)([a-z]{1,3}[- ][a-z]{1,2} ?\d{1,4})(\D|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2 ) ), '_ -', '_' ),
         REGEXP_INSTR(  value, '([^a-z]|^)([a-z]{1,3}[- ][a-z]{1,2} ?\d{1,4})(\D|$)', 1, 1, 1, 'i', 2 ) - 1
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         TRANSLATE( UPPER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^a-z]|^)([a-z]{1,3}[- ][a-z]{1,2} ?\d{1,4})(\D|$)', next_pos, 1, 'i', 2 ) ), '_ -', '_' ),
         REGEXP_INSTR(  value, '([^a-z]|^)([a-z]{1,3}[- ][a-z]{1,2} ?\d{1,4})(\D|$)', next_pos, 1, 1, 'i', 2 ) - 1
  FROM   items
  WHERE  next_pos > 0
)
SELECT item,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   items
WHERE  item IS NOT NULL AND NEXT_POS > 0
GROUP BY item
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ITEM     | COUNT(*)
> :------- | -------:
> CCC3333  |        1
> AAA1     |        4
> XXY427   |        1
> ABCRM10  |        1
> ABCLX283 |        1
> BBBB222  |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=22d0177ca4350ecdb4d3025388939a64)*

> The result should be a list of customers ...

You haven't given any information on how customers relate to this; that part is left as an exercise to the reader (who hopefully has the client values somewhere and can correlate them to the input).

---

**Update**:

If you want the count of unique number plates per row then:

```sql
WITH items ( rid, value, item, next_pos ) AS (
  SELECT ROWID,
         value,
         TRANSLATE( UPPER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^a-z]|^)([a-z]{1,3}[- ][a-z]{1,2} ?\d{1,4})(\D|$)', 1, 1, 'i', 2 ) ), '_ -', '_' ),
         REGEXP_INSTR(  value, '([^a-z]|^)([a-z]{1,3}[- ][a-z]{1,2} ?\d{1,4})(\D|$)', 1, 1, 1, 'i', 2 ) - 1
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT rid,
         value,
         TRANSLATE( UPPER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '([^a-z]|^)([a-z]{1,3}[- ][a-z]{1,2} ?\d{1,4})(\D|$)', next_pos, 1, 'i', 2 ) ), '_ -', '_' ),
         REGEXP_INSTR(  value, '([^a-z]|^)([a-z]{1,3}[- ][a-z]{1,2} ?\d{1,4})(\D|$)', next_pos, 1, 1, 'i', 2 ) - 1
  FROM   items
  WHERE  next_pos > 0
)
SELECT LISTAGG( item, ' + ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY item ) AS items,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         rid,
         item
  FROM   items
  WHERE  item IS NOT NULL AND NEXT_POS > 0
)
GROUP BY rid;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ITEMS                    | COUNT(*)
> :----------------------- | -------:
> XXY427                   |        1
> ABCLX283 + ABCRM10       |        2
> AAA1 + BBBB222 + CCC3333 |        3
> AAA1                     |        1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e329898c9318eddcd2e42da1cd408f9c)*

Comment: I not only need the amount of different licence plates but also a list of those licence plates (e.g. ABC-RM 10 + ABC-LX 283). In the above example I don't get the meaning of the number column. Does it count the occurencies of a specific licence plate?

Comment: @simulacrum Yes, the `AAA1` number plate appears 4 times (in various different formats: `AA-A1`, `AA-A 1` and `aa a1`). You haven't give any information on how the `Customer` column is generated so, as I said in the last sentence, generating that but is an exercise for you as we don't have the information to do it.